# npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting `npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` error while trying to install any package using NPM. I know there are numerous threads on the same issue but I could not find any thread which can help me.

I have set the proxy & I think its something to do with proxy not being set correctly\not using the correct url.

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Is there any way to check the URL I am using while setting proxy is correct? Are there any steps I need to take in order rectify this issue?

[image]

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but it's also highly viewed. Could you please convert your image of the error message into actual text?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was setting proxy as

```
npm config set http_proxy=http://domain:8080
```

instead of using the correct way

```
npm config set proxy http://domain:8080
```

Comment: Note to viewers: make sure that proxy starts with `http://` and don't just write `someHost:1234`!

Answer (score 51):

Maybe it's because the proxy do not stand for **https**.
What I do is clear the proxy content of ~/.npmrc, or use

```
    npm config delete proxy
```

What's more, [nrm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nrm) is recommended for this problem.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of setting the proxy using`npm config set http_proxy=http://address:8080` go to ~/.npmrc and remove the proxy config. This resolved my issue.

Comment: and where is  ~/.npmrc located?

Comment: This resolved my issue. I just opened .npmrc and removed proxy line.

Comment: .npmrc is located at : C:\Users\computername\

Answer (score 9):

I got the exact same error and this is what i did.

```
npm config get proxy
```

and it returned "null"

Opened "C:\Users\Myname.npmrc" in a notepad and made some changes. This is how my .npmrc file looks now

```
http-proxy=http://proxyhost/:proxyport
strict-ssl=false
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 7):

I also faced this error but I was not working behind a proxy server at the moment so using `npm config set proxy=http://address:8080` couldn't help and `~/.npmrc` didn't contain any proxy setting either. The solution in my case was just to **restart my computer**.

Answer (score 5):

The solution which worked for me:

1. Delete proxy: `npm config delete proxy`
2. Check `npm config get proxy` which should return `null`

Now, check if you are able to install the package. If not working, try manually editing the config, type: `npm config edit`, remember you are in VI editor.

Add `;` before(for commenting out): 
`npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`

Save and exit the file `:x`

Now, try installing the packages. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

If your proxy config is fine, sometimes the problem can be a deprecated package-lock.json file, therefore it redirects to a non-existing artifactory, npm registry.

Try to delete the package-lock.json and try npm i again.

Comment: It was `yarn.lock` file but appreciate it. Spend almost an hour into this. I tried to install using yarn install but then on my windows machine there was a policy permission issue and I had to set  `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy` but while doing that it created a broken `yarn.lock` which after fixing the original issue it was broken.

Answer (score 3):

does your proxy require you to authenticate? because if it does, you might want you configure your proxy like this.

placeholder names.
*username* is a placeholder for your actual username.
*password* is a placeholder for your actual password.
*proxy.company.com* is a placeholder for your actualy proxy
*port" is your actualy port the proxy goes through. its usualy 8080

```
npm config set proxy "http://username:password@proxy.company.com:port"
npm config set https-proxy "http://username:password@proxy.company.com:port"
```

Comment: This was it! I had my domain in front of my username the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

It happens due to proxy errors:
try this in cmd
**npm config get proxy**
if this is not null, then go to
***c/users/computerName/.npmrc***
open this in notepad
now clear the proxy line completely
try the above cmd
if it is null
then install angular
**npm i -g @angular/cli**

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue but non of the above help then I tried this:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
```

After that everything worked as expected.
I hope it helps you guys

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in my Arch Linux distro with npm 14.3.0 (w/ npm 6.14.5). I simply deleted the ~/.npm directory and tried again and this time it worked.

Comment: Consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me removing the ~/Users/.npmrc from the folder helped.

Answer (score 1):

go to the directory `C:\Users\username` and delete the npmrc file

this solved my issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining *why* your proposed solution benefits the OP, that way future visitors will get more utility out of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable the proxy for HTTP requests:

```bash
npm config delete proxy
```

2. Disable the proxy for HTTPS requests:

```bash
npm config delete https-proxy
```

These commands remove the proxy configurations from the npm configuration file. After executing these commands, npm will no longer use a proxy for HTTP and HTTPS requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had incorrectly typed in the address as

```
http://addressOfProxy.8080
```

instead of

```
http://addressOfProxy:8080
```

(Notice the *colon* before the port number 8080.)

Answer (score 0):

First I check whether proxy is set for me or not using this :

```
npm config get proxy
```

It returned null then I run this command

```
npm config set strict-ssl=false
```

It disable strict-ssl for that cmd session.

You can see complete list of config using this

```
npm config list ls -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Set the proxy
npm set proxy http://username:password@companyProxy:8080

npm set https-proxy http://username:password@companyProxy:8080

npm config set strict-ssl false -g

NOTES: No special characters in password except @ allowed.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason my error kept pointing to the "proxy" property in the config file. Which was misleading. During my troubleshooting I was trying different values for the proxy and https-proxy properties, but would only get the error stating to make sure the proxy config was set properly, and pointing to an older value.

Using, NPM CONFIG LS -L   command lists all the properties and values in the config file. I was then able to see the value in question was matching the https-proxy, therefore using the https-proxy. So I changed the proxy (my company uses different ones) and then it worked.  figured I would add this, as with these subtle confusing errors, every perspective on it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just unset the proxy host using :

`unset HOST`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the latest npm version while installing packages using npm.

While installing JavaScript, mention the latest version of NodeJS. For example, while installing JavaScript using devtools, use the below code:

```
devtools i --javascript nodejs:10.15.1
```

This will download and install the mentioned NodeJS version. Try installing the packages with npm after updating the version. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables.

I thought mine were set correctly, as `http://username:password@proxyhost:proxyport`, but it turned out that they were actually causing the problem! After deleting those variables, and restarting the commant prompt, the npm commands worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, everybody giving their answer so I thought I write too.

I am having the same proxy issue as all others. To solve this I tried many solutions but it did not work.

Search **.npmrc** file name in **C:\Users\your_username** drive and than add this line:

> http://proxy.company.com:8888

[image]

I did only this and my is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check whether proxy is set for you or not

```
npm config get proxy
```

Step 2: If it returned `null` and you also don't want any proxy, go to ~/Users/.npmrc
Open the file and make sure it has the following written:

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Disable strict-ssl for cmd session

```
npm config set strict-ssl=false
```

**Try to npm install now**

*P.S Now if `get proxy` didn't return `null` check if the proxy is correct or else set it with*

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.example.com:6500
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the error was I wasn't being consistent in usage of package manager, previously I installed my all packages with `yarn` and now I was using `npm` to install `moment-timezone` package and was facing this error, when I tried to install the package with **yarn** it was done successfully with command `yarn add moment-timezone`

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me:

1. Delete proxy: npm config delete proxy. Also npm config delete https-proxy
2. Check
   npm config get proxy
   npm config get https-proxy
   This should return null
3. Now, check if you are able to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

I use WSL with Ubuntu distro. Had the same issue and none of the above solutions worked.

Ran the following command, then everything started working,

echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. `npm set https-proxy http://username:Password@proxyhost/:proxyport`
2. `npm config set strict-ssl false -g`
3. Try to install now (e.g. `npm i tailwind -g`)

Comment: What do you mean byt username:Password ? what proxy do you use ?

Comment: your username and your password. I am behind a vpn

Answer (score 0):

For me, my wifi network settings had DNS set to `8.8.8.8` I just removed that and ran `npm i` again and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I was having some proxy configuration in my `{$HOME}/.npmrc` file.
Clearing it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macOs turnoff or Pause Private Relay
goto iCloud setting then you will see Private Relay
that solved my issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I resolved downgrading `npm` version to default one provided with `Node.js` version that is being used.

I was having this issue using `Node.js 16.20.0` and `npm 9.6.4`. Once I downgraded `npm to 8.19.4`, the error was fixed.

Not sure about how much `npm` can be upgraded according to `Node.js` version in use.

List of versions can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is solely for users who are "**not connected to an organisation intranet** "
this issue can arise due to one of the following reasons

1. You messed up something in your system npm settings  you are using a
2. node version manager like nvm  (as was in my case ).

in both cases this issue is faced on your regular network

**Solution** :

```
npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

run these commands in these order what this does is sets you default registry from http to https (which was the issue in my case) . so that you can now access the registry without disabling ssh

Answer (score -1):

strict-ssl=false

> proxy = http://ip_address_of_proxy:8088 
>   https-proxy = https://ip_address_of_proxy:8088
>   registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score -1):

registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org/       in    /.npmrc
just this in and restar worked