# Received below error when install jasmine

Tags: automation, jasmine

install command -  npm install --save-dev jasmine-reporters@^2.0.0

Error
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "jasmine-reporters@2.0.0"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND br.psa br.psa:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Answer (score 0):

according to error have you set your proxy because, when I am in my college computer lab I get this kind of error often.

here some useful link for that

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8151

  [npm ERR network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193614/npm-err-network-getaddrinfo-enotfound)