# How can I avoid npm error ,getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I am trying an npm install in windows 7 from the commandline. It returns with this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/angular failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

If this is a proxy issue how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193614/npm-err-network-getaddrinfo-enotfound