# Npm “ENOTFOUND error” while installing ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, npm

I would like to install ReactJs. I have installed Nodejs then try to create ReactJs project folder, I use
**npx create-react-app my-app** as per ReactJs documentation But this is the error which I get:-

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.11.0.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ..\_logs\2020-12-22T14_02_16_883Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Check your config: ```reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com```

Comment: There are multiple hits when searching for the error...

Comment: how to solve `reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com` @szczocik

Comment: what do you get when you run this: ```npm config get proxy```

Comment: I get :- `null` @szczocik

Comment: Try deleting the proxy and double check your npm config for any issues. Please refer to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193614/npm-err-network-getaddrinfo-enotfound

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
C:\Users\username
```

and then Search

```
.npmrc
```

Open `.npmrc` file with Notepad and Delete everything and past

```
http_proxy=http://domain:8080
```

This Works For me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this line in the error message:

```
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.11.0.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
```

...you have `proxy.company.com` set as your proxy somewhere. Find that and fix it to the setting you actually need or else remove it if you need no proxy (which is the standard/typical case). In the latter case, use `npm config delete proxy` and then try to install.

Perhaps you were following the instructions at https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/ or a related tutorial that uses `proxy.company.com` in its examples.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting proxy as

npm config set http_proxy=http://domain:8080

instead of using the correct way

npm config set proxy http://domain:8080

e.g: npm config set proxy http://123.01.2.

If you're using windows you can find the domain address in the control panel> Network and internet >internet options > click connections tab > Lan settings. You should see your proxy address

Answer (score 0):

Use a different (Wi-Fi) network or a mobile hotspot. Then try again to create the react app:

```
npx create-react-app <project_name>
```

This works for me, hope it helps you.