# i am trying to create an react app but i always get this error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

```
PS C:\Users\HP> npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.localhost.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-02T18_03_04_410Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\HP>
```

i have tried chat gpt to solve but nothing helps

Comment: Do you have a proxy configuration?

Comment: actually i am using super old laptop fujitsu core i3 and i tried to set my proxy many times with the helps of chatgpt but i dont know in which port i have to edit it

Comment: Which version of node/npm are you using? Also, since network requests are going over `proxy.localhost.com`, what happens when you try to wget or curl https://registry.npmjs.org?

Comment: I would disable the proxy

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: and i am using latest version of npm and node

Comment: i have disabled it but still the same error

Answer (score -1):

Hey check these two examples.
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/4093

[Npm “ENOTFOUND error” while installing ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410386/npm-enotfound-error-while-installing-reactjs)

Looks like your machine is having trouble connecting to the npm registry.  Check your network settings.Ask again if no solution found.

Comment: i have tried but still no help same error  npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-03T09_49_07_632Z-debug-0.log