# npm pointing to different registry.npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, gradle, npm

I am trying to build gradle project in docker container via jenkins.
I logged into a private repo to get image to buildstep and started the build. my .npmrc file is pointing to another private repo. I am getting below npm error.

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Answer (score 0):

I think this question have alread a response.

You can see [SharpCoder response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193614/npm-err-network-getaddrinfo-enotfound).

This github URL can help you too [#8151](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8151#issuecomment-124860749)