# Unable to install NPM package create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm unable to install the `create-react-app` package, what could be the problem?

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyhost
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Arnab\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-20T13_04_28_280Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't create react code? What are you trying to do? What have you already tried?

Comment: *This is a problem related to network connectivity.* < Check if your network administrator, internet provider or antivirus software isn't blocking any requests to the NPM domain name. What happens if you go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app or https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app directly? Also make sure you are not on a VPN's or proxy settings that might be blocking traffic to the NPM websites as well

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193614/npm-err-network-getaddrinfo-enotfound)

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the messages:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
```

It is not the package that is not found - it is the `getaddrinfo` syscall that returned `ENOTFOUND`. This is a DNS resolution failure.

Comment: Sir how to solve the DNS resolution failure issue