# how to solve this issue of create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, makefile, proxy, create-react-app

npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your-proxy-url   , I am facing this issue while creating react app ,can anybody help how to solve this issue

I have tried all the best options available but this error is due to some proxy issue

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193614/npm-err-network-getaddrinfo-enotfound